# Create SQL string - probably involving DISTINCT, GROUP BY or ..?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, t-sql

I have this table `Test { Id:int, data:string }` - a table with two columns and n rows.

Facts:

- Id is unique (and tells something about the order the items have been added)
- data can have duplicates
- if items are grouped by data all the Id are consecutive

In LINQ I would do something like :

```
class Row
{
    public int Id      { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
public static class MyTestClass
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        IEnumerable<Row> rows = new List<Row>
        {
            new Row { Id = 1, Data = "42"},
            new Row { Id = 2, Data = "42"},
            new Row { Id = 3, Data = "11"},
            new Row { Id = 4, Data = "11"},
            new Row { Id = 5, Data = "11"},
            new Row { Id = 6, Data = "65"},
        };
        var result = rows.GroupBy(r => r.Data)
                         .OrderByDescending(g => g.First().Id)
                         .Select(g => g.Key)
                         .ToList();
        var str = string.Join(" ", result);
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

This would print :

> 65
>
> 11
>
> 42

How do I write this in an effecient way in SQL (for MS SQL)? I've been around different soluions like `"SELECT DISTINCT Data, Id FROM Test ORDER BY Id DESC"` but this apparently this returns distinct based on both columns - which is obviously not what I want :)

Comment: Why do you want an arbitrary ID at all?

Comment: I sorry I don't understand your question. The Ids are just autogenerated and incremented by 1 for each new row - am I missing something?

Comment: I thought the LINQ would just be a sample. But anyway, `First` will not return the lowest, oldest, newest or highest ID, just an arbitrary ID. The same as `MAX` or `MIN` in SQL does. Therefor i've asked why you need this ID since it has no meaning.

Comment: Ah. As I tried to write "if items are grouped by data all the Id are consecutive". I meant that a grouping by data would contain an interval of Ids that does not overlap with any other groupings Ids. Thus an arbitary ID from all the groups would give the correct ordering (edit: of the groups).

Comment: And if you write that this means that the Id is irrelevant in result you are absolutely right :) - English is not my spoken language and sometimes it's not easy for me to get it right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
SELECT Data, MAX(Id)
FROM Test 
GROUP BY Data
ORDER BY MAX(Id) DESC
```

**UPDATE:**

Since Id should be with an aggregate function and it is irrelevant with the author's requirement, hence i have used MAX function, any other function can be used , i guess.

Comment: You cant order by id when id is not in the select clause.

Comment: This does not work in T-SQL. You cannot order by or select  a column that is not part of the group by or aggregated in another way(f.e. MAX(ID)).

Comment: No, sorry (I tried that as well) - this gives the exception : Column 'Test.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Sorry to no - still : Column "Test.Id" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: As i've said already, you cannot order by a column that is not part of the group by or aggregated. So you need also apply the `MAX` also in the `Order By`.

Comment: @JoeTuskan: It works. He wants the highest ID (actually an arbitrary ID) and he gets the highest ID of each data-group. So what's wrong with it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I was mistaken. I thought the OP wanted the IDs for some reason.

Comment: The last edit did it. It works beautifully now. Just to understand it. The MAX(Id)in "ORDER BY MAX(Id) DESC" - is it referring to the group from "GROUP BY Data"? (Thanks for the effort, btw).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Test.Data
FROM (SELECT Data
    FROM Test
    GROUP BY Data) as Grouping
    INNER JOIN Test on Test.Data = Grouping.Data
ORDER BY Test.Id DESC
```

I would try this

Comment: How order by will be work here. Please see my answer's comment.

Comment: @sarwar026, It's a member of the Test table.

Comment: ohh sorry really. I should be more cautious next time.